# Updates on an entity object not firing before delete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So basically I'm trying to do this sequence of events in entity framework.

1. Create a new account
2. Get an existing account
3. Move all the data from the old account to the new account (transactions, users, etc)
4. Delete the old account

I'm doing this all in 'one go', inside a single ObjectContext.

It fails when I call SaveChanges on the context. I get an foreign key constraint error.

I checked this in SQL profiler and it turns out that entity framework isn't sending any of the updates, just the selected and then a delete.

I kinda understand WHY it is working like that but there must be some way to force it do work properly, without having to call SaveChanges() twice or something.

Hopefully.

---

My merge function basically looks like this

```
public void Merge(Account newAccount, Account oldAccount)
{
    // ...

    foreach (var user in oldAccount.Users.ToList())
    {
        oldAccount.Users.Remove(user);
        newAccount.Users.Add(user);
    }

    // ...

    _unitOfWork.Accounts.Delete(oldAccount);
}
```

The objects are POCO objects created by the E.F.4 POCO Entity Generator. To avoid pasting the entire class here's just one of the association properties with it's 'fixup' function.

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        if (_users == null)
        {
            var newCollection = new FixupCollection<User>();
            newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupUsers;
            _users = newCollection;
        }
        return _users;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_users, value))
        {
            var previousValue = _users as FixupCollection<User>;
            if (previousValue != null)
            {
                previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupUsers;
            }
            _users = value;
            var newValue = value as FixupCollection<User>;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupUsers;
            }
        }
    }
}   

private void FixupUsers(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (User item in e.NewItems)
        {
            item.Account = this;
        }
    }

    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (User item in e.OldItems)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(item.Account, this))
            {
                item.Account = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you doing change tracking?  Are you using proxies, or are you calling `DetectChanges`?

Comment: How are you doing change tracking?  Are you using proxies, or are you calling `DetectChanges`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured out the solution. @CodeGorilla's comment gave me a hint.

Essentially I just need to call

```
_context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
```

before trying to delete the account. This forces entity framework to do all the updates in the database. After that there is no problem with deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You use object as reference  to add and remove inside the for loop , the best solution to get object by key instate of using an object when add.

```
 oldAccount.Users.Remove(user);
 newAccount.Users.Add(users.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.ID = user.Id));
```